# How to push popup notifications with plyer in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I,m trying to make a window popup even if the app is not opened or if another app is opened and running. I know how to make a normal notifications that appears and disappears after a short time but I don't know how to go about pushing a popup notification as I am new to plyer.